# AWS ImportImage operation: S3 bucket does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to import a windows 2012 OVA file into aws. I'm using this documentation.

[AWS VMWare Import](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/import-vm-image.html)

I've created an s3 bucket to store the OVA files, and the OVA files have been uploaded there.

And when I try to import the images files into AWS, I get an error:

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "server1" --disk-containers file://containers.json --profile=company-dlab_us-east-1

An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: S3 bucket does not exist: s3://companyvmimport/
```

Which is strange because I can list the bucket I'm trying to upload to using the aws command line:

```
 aws s3 ls --profile=company-dlab_us-east-1
2016-10-20 09:52:33 companyvmimport
```

This is my containers.json file:

```
[
  {
      "Description": "server1",
      "Format": "ova",
      "UserBucket": {
       "S3Bucket": "s3://companyvmimport/",
       "S3Key": "server1.ova"
  }
}]
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an issue in your copy/paste, in your `containers.json` file you reference bucket as `s3://companyvmimport` but you have error about `kpmgvmimport`

anyway **you dont need to indicate the s3 protocol in the json**

your JSon file should look like

```
[
  {
      "Description": "server1",
      "Format": "ova",
      "UserBucket": {
       "S3Bucket": "companyvmimport",
       "S3Key": "server1.ova"
  }
}]
```

If the file is not right at the "root" of the bucket you need to indicate full path.

Comment: sorry, no that was an error on my part trying to obscure the company name. I've corrected the example so that it makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: ok can you confirm it is working when you remove the S3 protocol part in the S3Bucket parameter

Comment: ok. I tried removing the protocol from the containers.json file.That part seems to be working! However now it seems that my user doesn't have access to the s3 bucket. Even tho he should have the correct policy attached. Here are the details [s3 access problem](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/36f9fb66e260b64076e1aa85f3439464) I even tried giving the user AmazonS3FullAccess. Still no dice. Same result.

Comment: Update. I've tried giving my user full admin rights to AWS with this policy: AdministratorAccess

Still no dice. I'm getting this error when I try to upload the file using the import command:

`An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: User does not have access to the S3 object`

Comment: One more thing I tried. I've verified that I can download the file to my workstation using the s3cmd command: `[root@salt ~]# s3cmd get s3://kpmgvmimport/server1.ova .
download: 's3://companyvmimport/server1.ova' -> './server1.ova'  [1 of 1]
 0 of 0     0% in    0s     0.00 B/s  done`  And I can list the file ` ls -lh server1.ova
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.0G Oct 20 15:27 server1.ova` 

Very odd, I wonder why I don't have permission to upload the file using the import command!

Comment: hum do you have bucket policy ?

Comment: Thanks. I found I had to create a custom policy for the S3 bucket giving my user permissions to it. This is the bucket policy I created:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1476979061000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::companyvmimport",
                "arn:aws:s3:::companyvmimport/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: And then the import command started working correctly:
`aws ec2 import-image --description "Windows 2008 OVA" --disk-containers file://containers.json --profile=copmany-dlab
Windows 2008 OVA        import-ami-ffyqev9c     2       active  pending
SNAPSHOTDETAILS 0.0     OVA
USERBUCKET      kpmgvmimport    server1.ova`

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment in the answer, about setting the custom policy on the S3 bucket, contains JSON that may grant access to everyone (which may not be what's desired).

If you add a Principal statement to the JSON you can limit the access to just yourself.

I ran into this same issue (User does not have access to the S3 object), and after fighting it for a while, with the help of this post and some further research, finally figured it out. I opened [a separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920837/aws-import-image-user-does-not-have-access-to-the-s3-object/40920838#40920838) specifically for this "does not have access" issue.